# IUSR Access rights doesn't work on IIS8

Tags: iis8

I have a strange issue:

I have created a website on IIS and put some static html and js/css there. Everthing seems good. I have noticed that the folder's NTFS rights is granted to IUSR full control.

When I make some configuration (something unimportant) and the `web.config` file is auto generate in this folder, the website send 500 errors (I have noticed that `web.config`'s NTFS access is granted to IUSR full control too.

I have tried several methods to solve this issue, but all attempts failed, except one: granting the full control access rights to EVERYONE on the website folder.

Is there a better solution? Or is this the only solution? If so, this would be weird!

Answer (score 1):

The application pool is probably running as a different user than the IUSR. Here is an article that explains how to update the NTFS permissions in IIS7. The steps are the same for IIS8.

Comment: I think  you forgot the link

Comment: I know what you mean. The new account in IIS7 OR IIS8 running application pool is something named ApplicatioPoolIdentity , I have attempted to apply the permission for the folders to IIS AppPool\<pool name> , but that even can't pass the "Check Name", what's your opinion?

Comment: The user is a local user. If you are on a domain, make sure you choose the local machine. Beyond that, you should be able to simply type in iis apppool\apppoolname and successfully check the name and add it to the NTFS permissions.